# Matplotlib on zoom event the legend picker isnt updated

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the code below that hides/shows a line. However it doesn't seem to work when I zoom in. The legend needs to be refreshed somehow?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True)

ax[0].grid(True)
ax[0].set_title(date)
lines1 = ax[0].plot(x, y)

ax[1].set_xlabel('time')
ax[1].grid(True)
lines2 = ax[1].plot(x2, y2)

leg1 = fig.legend(lines1, header1, 'upper left')
leg2 = fig.legend(lines2, header2, 'lower left')

lined = dict()
for legline, origline in zip(leg1.get_lines(),lines1):
    legline.set_picker(5)
    lined[legline] = origline
for legline, origline in zip(leg2.get_lines(),lines2):
    legline.set_picker(5)
    lined[legline] = origline

def onpick(event):
        legline = event.artist
        origline = lined[legline]
        vis = not origline.get_visible()
        origline.set_visible(vis)
        if vis:
            legline.set_alpha(1.0)
        else:
            legline.set_alpha(0.2)
        fig.canvas.draw()


    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

Comment: Would you mind spending some more words on the actual outcome and in how far that differs from the expected outcome? I currently don't see the problem.

Comment: When the plot is displayed the onpick event is triggered when clicking on an item on the legend. Once I use the zoom functionality of matplotlib and then click on a item again on the legend it doesnt trigger the onpick event again.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to click on the zoom button again. Mentioned here:

http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/pick-event-after-zooming-panning-stops-working-td43812.html